# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'C000000055' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT
cast(co_num as varchar),
activity_date, 
due_date 
FROM coitem_log_mst
WHERE cast(co_num as varchar) = 3199 and co_line = 10 and co_release = 0
ORDER BY activity_date
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'C000000055' to data type int.
```

I have tried various conversions and putting the co_num value in ' '. But still get the error. Please advise...

Comment: First of all, never use `varchar` without explicitly giving it a length. Also, if you are converting to `varchar`, why are you comparing it to a value that's an `int`?. Use `cast(co_num as varchar(20) = '3199'`

Comment: You're casting to varchar, and then comparing with an integer. Why? Compare with a varchar, and you're be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without single quotes the `3199` you're comparing it to is an `INT`.  It's attempting to convert the value into an `INT` to do the comparison, and one of your values (`C000000055`) cannot be converted to an `INT`.

Add single quotes (`'`) around `3199` to compare it as a `VARCHAR`:

```
Select  Cast(co_num As Varchar)
      , activity_date
      , due_date
From    coitem_log_mst
Where   Cast(co_num As Varchar) = '3199' 
        And co_line = 10
        And co_release = 0
Order By activity_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would just use `try_convert()`.  However, your column already appears to be a character string, so how about:

```
SELECT co_num , activity_date,  due_date 
FROM coitem_log_mst
WHERE co_num = '3199' and co_line = 10 and co_release = 0
ORDER BY activity_date;
```

Note:  If `co_line` is a string or `co_release` is a string, then you should enclose those values in single quotes:

```
WHERE co_num = '3199' and co_line = '10' and co_release = '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as you are comparing co_num as a varchar, you must single quote right hand value.

```
SELECT
cast(co_num as varchar),
activity_date, 
due_date 
FROM coitem_log_mst
WHERE cast(co_num as varchar) = '3199' and co_line = 10 and co_release = 0
ORDER BY activity_date
```